# getting stack trace for app that was not installed through Google Play

Tags: android, stack-trace, crash-reports

I sent my app to several users via Email. It can be installed like this on several test user devices quite easily.

Now I need to get the stack trace from a crash of the app similar to the trace that is available for apps sold through Google Play.

Are there any "comfortable" possibilities?

While I have my own logging which I write to a log file so the test users can send me my own created logs, I certainly cannot catch all crash situations myself.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out ACRA http://code.google.com/p/acra/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://www.zubhium.com/
add some code to your app, give your friends the url and they can test it. You get full report, control over installations etc.

> Platform for Android beta distribution, real time crash analytics & support deck for your users.
>
> Zubhium realtime crash reporter finds, tracks crashes in your betas or market app. (supports offline crash reporting). Our platform analyzes crash with granular details. Enable auto crash reporting by embedding two lines of lightweight SDK within two minutes.